# Why is this transaction I made being rejected?

Tags: transactions, replace-by-fee

I created an RBF transaction and bumped the fee, which was broadcast. Now, I am trying to bump the fee a second time, but get a "missing inputs error".

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the tx I want to bump a second time: [f042…e9c0](https://blockchain.info/tx/f04244bb95413babb590f37c6971b15be68b827b56fd504ea0fe8c30f93ce9c0)

This is the signed tx:

```
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
```

Comment: SOLVED: Seems I was spending the output of the previous tx

Comment: In that case, please write a short answer to your own question and accept. That will be much clearer if someone else searches for the same problem.

Comment: SOLVED: Seems I was spending the output of the previous tx

Comment: Don't write a comment, write an answer :)

Comment: hmm I did write an answer but for some reason it said "your post was converted to a comment" ill try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was spending the output of the previous tx thats why the transaction was rejected